# Code does not seem to be pulling data from database for comparison

Tags: php, preg-match

This is an attempt to discover if an event in WordPress Events Manager has a URL defined in its attributes. The URL is listed in the database under the column event_attributes:

```
a:1:{s:9:"band_link";s:18:"http://www.robertearlkeen.com";}
```

And the database column event_slug matches the post name.

I call the function here:

```
<?php filterURL();?>
```

The PHP:

```
function filterURL(){


    /// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    /// Read and parse data
    $sql = "SELECT event_slug, event_attributes FROM wp_em_events";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $slug = $row["event_slug"];
            $bandURL = $row["event_attributes"];
            $pageSlug = $post->post_name;
                if ($pageSlug == $eventSlug && stripos($bandURL, 'html') !== false) { 
                    echo "<a href='" . $bandURL . ">Band Website</a>";
                }
            }

       }

    return;

    mysqli_close($conn);

}
```

Comment: WTF is this? `preg_match($post->post_name == $eventSlug && "/html/i", $bandURL)`

Answer (score 0):

This part

```php
if (preg_match($post->post_name == $eventSlug && "/html/i", $bandURL)){ 
    echo "<a href='" . $bandURL . ">Band Website</a>";
}
```

should be

```php
if ($post->post_name == $eventSlug && stripos($bandURL, 'html') !== false) {
    echo "<a href=\"{$bandURL}\">Band Website</a>";
}
```

`stripos` is faster than `preg_match` and can be used in this scenario, because you just want to check whether `$bandURL` contains `html`.

Comment: Blinding, thanks for the advice, but it didn't work. Nothing printed to the screen.

Comment: I made changes based on BlindingLight's comments and added another variable to clean it up, but it still isn't printing to the screen. Why?

Comment: Place ```error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);``` and ```ini_set('display_errors', 1);``` before your code to see errors. As I can see ```$eventSlug``` and ```$post``` variables are undefined. If you just comment out the if part and leave the echo, does it output anything?